# Execute python script from a installed package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a Python package that contains a script:

```
pip show -f my-package
```

Results in

```
my-package-path/script.py
```

I would like to execute script.py, something like:

```
pip install my-package
python3 my-package-path.script.py
```

But it doesn't work. What's the standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access and  modify `my-package` setup.py (if setuptools is used) - you could add entry_points to `setup()` call and if thats done correctly, you can run the script directly as its added to the path. Example:

```py
NAME="AISTool"

setup(
    name=f"{NAME}",
    # ... extra stuff removed ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            f'{NAME}=AISTool.main:main'
        ],
    },
    # ... extra stuff removed ...
)
```

Now, when that package gets installed, there will be an executable called `AISTool` which runs `main()` method from `AISTool.main`